# concise way of making an R formula

Tags: r, dataframe

I apologize if this has already been asked before, but I can't even think of a great way to describe the issue I have. Basically, I have a dataframe that has 30 columns in it. I want to use randomForest on it to predict one of the columns, but I also don't want to manually type each of the remaining 29 columns. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `y~.`.  This is definitely a duplicate.

Comment: Could you link to that thread, Ari?

Comment: I get the following error for apply:

"Error in if (n == 0) stop("data (x) has 0 rows") : 
  argument is of length zero"

Any suggestions as to why? Also, doesn't your method lack the ability to specify which column you're trying to predict? Remember randomForest looks like randomForest(col1 ~ col2 + col3 + col4, data=train)? I'm new to R, sorry if I'm asking basic questions.

Comment: Do you have a link to the data or paste up an example?

Comment: I'm using the Forest Cover data from Kaggle. https://www.kaggle.com/c/forest-cover-type-prediction/data - I'm just trying to get a feel for the data, really. I want to see how randomForest predicts things.

Comment: Have you tried: `randomForest( col1 ~ . , data=train)`?

Comment: Oh, that worked perfect, BondedDust. Thanks so much! This will save me quite a bit of time in the future.